# FTP - automatically rename/move file on FTP server when it's downloaded

Tags: bash, ftp

I need to make a script for an FTP server that will detect when a file is downloaded and then either rename or move or delete that file to prevent it from being re-downloaded. Is there a way to do this by storing a file on the FTP server that will always be looking for when a file is downloaded, and then executing that process? I assume it could be done with a bash script, but I dont know enough about them to know if it can be constantly running/checking for if a file is downloaded.

Thanks!

Comment: If you control/own the FTP server and can run programs on it, you could probably do something with `inotify` https://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not control/own it. I can only upload/download files under a certain directory. The people who use the FTP asked me to do something that involves the task listed in my question.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. When re-posting there, make sure you share details about your FTP server.